# Doing something right after a for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async.js

As you know, NodeJS is asynchronous. But it's a bit disapointing.

For example, as long as i understood, a condition will be synchronous while loop will be asynchronous.

My question is how to wait a for loop end ? I've heard about async.js but i can't see how i can use it for my case.

Having this :

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MAX_INDEX; i++)
    if ((buffer >> i) & 1) { // If the bit is set
        result.push(i)
    }
```

How can i do some task after the result is successfully filled ?

Comment: Please elaborate, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That for loop is synchronous. So you can just write your next instruction after the loop.
Or probably I miss something.

Comment: You understood wrong. *Some* tasks are asynchronous, like waiting for a response from a remote server or timers, but at the core JS is synchronous, as is your code.

Comment: So if i write code right after the for loop, i will be sure that the result array is fullfilled ?

So what an async function imply in code ? How can we do a async function ? Is it only about process.nextTick() ?

Comment: No, it's not only about `process.nextTick()`. It depends on what you need to achieve. Internet is full of articles about how to manage async code in javascript. In general accessing external resources (network, filesystem, ecc...) is an async task.

Comment: That' why i firslty though. But supposing i put a return right after the loop, will it return the result fullfilled or not ?

Comment: It will. Actually @Littlesquirrel why don't you test that?

Comment: Well, i was really sure to already have test it for a moment, and it wasn't work, so i accepted that. But according on what i learned from now, maybe the test i've done was async.

Comment: use setTimeout() function it will execute after the time out

Answer (score -1):

You can use flag bits in your code here is the sample

```
for(var i = 0; i < MAX_INDEX; i++)
  {

  if((buffer >> i) & 1)
  {
  var f=0;
  var main=result.push(i);
  break;
  }
  }
  if(f==0){
  f++;
  return main;
  console.log(main);
  }
  else{
  .......
  }
```